# How to build an unique number for a tupel in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to identify a unique number for the Tupels

I have in the database product table and parts table and every product has parts (1:n).

| product | parts |
| --- | --- |
| A | x |
| A | y |
| A | v |

What I want to have is a unique number for the combination between the product and its three parts, or I want to have a unique number for the tuple of parts.

So that's how it should look like at the end

| product | partsID |
| --- | --- |
| A | (unique number) |

Comment: [`DENSE_RANK`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dense-rank-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)?

Comment: Seems unnecessary can you explain why you think you need this.

Comment: Hmm, I missed it initially but you already have them as 1-to-many. So what is that really you are asking? That PartsId is foreign key, no?

Comment: Concatenate the three parts_id and then hash it?

Comment: my guess is more than one product can use the same parts so a junction table containing productid and partid may be helpful.

Comment: Hmm, my guess is that what they have shown us is already this junction table and they want to generate some sort of Id that uniquely represents the combination of parts

Comment: regarding your question p.Salmon. I have a huge database and don't have access to change the formatting of tables.

in the database there is a table for the employee entries and other tables for the stored data (such as how many parts this product has or what type of production defect can be attributed to this product)

The main problem, when the employee enters that part x in product A has a production defect, the remaining parts will trigger themselves (in the entry table ).

by the way the parts also have subset. and the same problem also happens when a subset is entered by the employ

Comment: That's why I want to compare the product parts in stored data with employee entries.

and as you said the product can use the same parts.  so to joining the tables will not work

Comment: @MartinSmith yes that's exacly what i want to generate !

Comment: Imagine a defect is detected in part x then I would want to  know all products that use part x to do so you would need to know the relationship between part and products and I don't think any sort of hashed key would be helpful for this problem- on the other hand I may just not understand the question.

Comment: yeah after the clarification the hashing won't help you. If you need to see all parts that are affected and parts can contain other parts probably you need some sort of recursive CTE query

Comment: Unfortunately i couldn't solve the problem so far. i have an idea but idont know how to implement it. the idea is to get the ASCII-code for every part  then to add up the ASCII-Code of the three rows together. But that did not work well, because ASCII() is just providing the first char in the string. i would appreciate it if someone can tell me how get the ASCII-CODE for the entire string

Comment: A product is the sum of its parts. Wouldn't a 'sum of its parts' id represent the same thing as product id?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT product, CHECKSUM_AGG(CHECKSUM(Parts)) AS partID
FROM table
GROUP BY product
```